# doxygen - How to hide a class without hidding its members in subclasses?

Tags: documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

I have a code (in C++, but for other languages solution of problem is probably similar):

```
namespace details {
  struct C {
    /// Documentation for common method.
    void c();
  };
};

/// Documentation for class A
struct A: public details:C {
  /// Documentation for method a
  void a();
};

/// Documentation for class B    
struct B: public details:C {
  /// Documentation for method b
  void b();
};
```

And I want to hide class C (and whole details namespace) in documentation (it exists only to make A and B implementation shorter). But I need to have A and B in documentation, **with c member (and all other members inherited from C) documented**, like for source:

```
/// Documentation for class A
struct A {
  /// Documentation for method a
  void a();

  /// Documentation for common method.
  void c();
};

/// Documentation for class B    
struct B {
  /// Documentation for method b
  void b();

  /// Documentation for common method.
  void c();
};
```

How to do this properly?

Comment: Have you tried setting `INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB` to `YES`?